# Paypal (NVP APIs) how to discount for the order?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

For example, this is my request paramaters,the order total is 270.00, if I want to use a coupon($10.00) to discount this order, than the order total must be 260.00, but now, I can't find any about discount AMT parameter in this api (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), I neglect it?

```
Array(        
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 270.00
    **[some parameter? DISCOUNT_AMT ?] => 10.00 // have this parameter ??**
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 219.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 39.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 12.00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 219.00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Goods title
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Goods description
);
```

Sorry about my poor English, thanks for buddies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add the discount as an additional line item with a negative value and then adjust the ITEMAMT and AMT accordingly.

```
Array(        
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 260.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 209.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 39.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 12.00
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 219.00
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Goods title
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Goods description
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1] => -10.00
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1] => 1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1] => Discount
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1] => Coupon Code ABC123
```

);

Comment: Thanks for you answer, if there are more than two goods in this order, but I just want to discount the order that minus the order total but not against the goods(AMT), for your example, it's discount for goods,but not order total,I apologize for my English that hope you understand what I said :)

Comment: Are you saying you would want to the subtotal to be 0.00 but then you would still have shipping and handling?

Comment: Yeah,if the subtotal is $99.0,and I have a coupon($10.0),the subtotal to be $89.0, and still have shipping and handing, and PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT still not change.

Comment: Ok, yeah, the subtotal would be 89 like you said.  You just need to make sure that ITEMAMT + SHIPPINGAMT + HANDLINGAMT + TAXAMT = AMT.

Comment: You are very kind, THX :)